# Merging PDF files with PDFTK with the same 4 numbers in the file name

Tags: windows-10, powershell, pdftk

I have a folder with PDF files (`C:\1_PDF`). There's two types of file names, `330526.pdf` and `000526.pdf`. Those files names do change (increase by number) `330527.pdf`, `330528.pdf`, `330529.pdf`. Same goes for the `000526.pdf` series.

Now, I'd like the code to go through the files in the folder and merge all the files with the identical last four digits in the file name (`xx**0526**.pdf`). There can be 1 or there can be 200 of those file pairs.

The merging itself was not a problem, this is how I solved it:

```
pdftk A=330526.pdf B=000526.pdf shuffle A B output RG-330526.pdf
```

But the loop is what's killing me.  How can I do that?

I went through pretty much everything i could find with Google and still no solution. I hope I can get some help in here.

Comment: You can use wildcards, like "pftk *0526.pdf output rg-0526.pdf"

Comment: Hi Silbee, that works. I just had to change the file because in the output file the 00*.pdf is the first page but all those files shoud be the last. So changing to "e00*.pdf" helped me sorting the files in that folder. So now the "00*.pdf" ist put at the end of the "33*.pdf" .

But now, like i said, those numbers change every day. How can i oop it (make it go from the first to the last file in that folder)

Comment: Ahh i see. So you always have a file pair starting with 000xxxx and 330xxxx and the xxxx part increments and you want all of the pairs to form one pdf file per pair ?

Comment: Exactly :) Just like that!

Comment: I just changed the file names of the "000xxx" files to "e0xxx" for sorting reasons. JFYI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My powershell is rusty, but i can help you towards achieving a result.

First of, we could make a list of "first" pages with powershell's Get-ChildItem as following

```
$firstPageList = Get-ChildItem C:\1_PDF\e0* -File -Name
```

Next, we iterate through each name on the list

```
ForEach ($firstPage in $firstPageList) {
```

Lets find its pair, the second page

```
    $secondPage = "330" + $firstPage.substring(4)
```

Create a name for your output

```
    $output = "RG-$secondPage"
```

And finally execute your command

```
    iex "pdftk A=$firstPage B=$secondPage shuffle A B output $output"
```

For testing purposes, you can replace iex with Write-Host to just get visual output of what command will be called.

And end the for loop

```
}
```

The way its written now, you'll have to run it from C:\1_PDF.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work, I tried different things, no chance to get it to work.

This is the code:

$firstPageList = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Test\Desktop\PDF_Temp\3* -File -Name

ForEach ($firstPage in $firstPageList) {

$secondPage = "e0" + $firstPage.substring(2)

$output = "RG-$firstPage"

#Invoke-Expression pdftk A=$firstPage B=$secondPage shuffle A B output $output
Write-Host pdftk A=$firstPage B=$secondPage shuffle A B output $output

}

This is the error i get:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUo17.png)

Write-Host looks good to me:

[Write-Host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RX4Yh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Got it! This works perfectly:

```
$firstPageList = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Test\Desktop\PDF_Temp\3* -File -Name

ForEach ($firstPage in $firstPageList)
{

$secondPage = "e0" + $firstPage.substring(2)

$output = "RG-$firstPage"

Invoke-Command {pdftk A=$firstPage B=$secondPage shuffle A B output $output}}


get-childitem -Recurse -path "C:\Users\Test\Desktop\PDF_Temp\" -filter '3*.pdf' | move-item -Destination "D:\Bank\QR_ES\2_versendet"

get-childitem -Recurse -path "C:\Users\Test\Desktop\PDF_Temp\" -filter 'e*.pdf' | move-item -Destination "D:\Bank\QR_ES\2_versendet"
```

Thank you very much Silbee!

Comment: Glad i could help. Great to see your own contributions to solving the problem and not expecting a fully working script.

Comment: I guess i need your help again lol. Did you see my new post?

https://superuser.com/questions/1668087/pdftk-burst-initial-file-name