# PDFTK burst, initial file name control

Tags: powershell, pdftk

Using to PDFTK `burst` a multipage PDF file into single files, I need  a way for it to allow me to control the first file name and the number it starts for the output file naming convention.

**For example** I'd like the initial file name  for the first page it extracts to its own PDF file to have the name of: "`e00526.pdf`". This way it "burst" the multipage PDF file incrementally as such: "`e00526.pdf`", "`e00527.pdf`", "`e00528.pdf`" etc. output file name wise.

For now this is what I have:

```
#[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null
#$firsFile = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter first file name:", "File name")

$firstFile = "e00526"

$QRDir = "C:\1_PDF"

chdir $QRDir

$output = "e00526%d.pdf"

pdftk input.pdf burst output $output
```

However, this gives a burst file output naming standard with a `1` appended to the end of the base file name for the first page extracted to its own PDF file. Then it increments that appended `1` by `1` for each subsequent extracted page.

So this is what this code does: **"`e005261.pdf`", "`e005262.pdf`", "`e005263.pdf`"**, etc.

What I need: **"`e00526.pdf`", "`e00527.pdf`", "`e00528.pdf`"** etc.

So instead of appending the **`1`** after the **`6`** in the file name, it should increase the **`6`** to a **`7`**, etc. but starting with the second extracted page so I control the starting page `1` file name.

---

**Update**

I don't think that could work like that because of this sorting issue:

[Sorting issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWJqv.png)

The "e005261.pdf" should become the "e00526.pdf"
and
The "e0052611.pdf" should become the "e00537.pdf"

That's why I think it would make the whole thing a lot easier if we just find a way to give it the first file name and let it increase 1 digit after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a file rename post PDFTK operation solution that will use logic to get the base file name parts and set them as `int` data types, calculate these for the incremental number values you desire, and then concatenate those together accordingly to use for the new base file of each file.

### PowerShell

**Note:** Remove`-Whatif` from the below PowerShell to run the logic rather than it tell you what'll happen if it runs. Also, If you need to recursively traverse subfolders within `C:\1_PDF\` you can add the `-Recurse` parameter in the `Get-ChildItem` command (i.e. `Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\1_PDF\*.pdf" -Recurse`).

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\1_PDF\*.pdf" | % { Process { 
    $firstFile = [string]$_.Basename;
    Try { [int]$fnameF = $firstFile[1..5] -join ""} Catch {};
    Try { [int]$fnameL = $firstFile[6..99] -join ""} Catch {};
    $f = Try { [convert]::ToInt32($firstFile[6..99] -join "", 10) } Catch {};
    If ( $f -is [int] ) { 
        Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "$($_.BaseName[0])$(([string]($fnameF+$fnameL-1)).PadLeft(5,"0"))$($_.Extension)" -WhatIf;
        } Else {
        Write-Host "$($_.BaseName)$($_.Extension) does not end with numerical digits in its basename." -ForegroundColor Yellow 
        };
    }};
```

### Supporting Resources

- > `Get-ChildItem` usually returns a `FileInfo` object. Those objects
  > contain a few useful properties—among them are...
  >
  > - the full path, file name, and extension (`FullName`),
  > - the path alone (`DirectoryName`),
  > - the file name (`Name`), and
  > - the file name without its extension (`BaseName`)
  >
  > [Source](https://4sysops.com/archives/split-path-get-childitem-splitting-file-names-in-powershell/)
- [Rename-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7.1)
- [Define PowerShell Data Types](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-datatypes.html)
- [PowerShell Operators](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html)
  -[Find the Index Number of a Value in a PowerShell Array](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/find-the-index-number-of-a-value-in-a-powershell-array/)
- [Try {...} Catch {...} Finally {...}](https://ss64.com/ps/try.html)
- [about_Arithmetic_Operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arithmetic_operators?view=powershell-7.1)
- [String.PadLeft Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=net-5.0)

Comment: THIS now works perfectly!! Thanks Doughboy!

Comment: Done :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Lets try like last time.

Renaming the files is going to be an issue as you have described yourself, so lets think of a different way.

We could extract page by page and define our own filename every page. First thing we need is to find the number of pages, this should work with the following command:

```
$totalPages = pdftk $firstFile dump_data | Select-String "NumberOfPages"
```

Now lets set up some things to get started.

```
#First we determine our starting number by dropping the first letter from the filename and turning it into an integer.
$startingNumber = [int]$firstFile.substr(1)
$currentNumber = $startingNumber

#Now we iterate through every page we want to extract
For ($i = 1; i -le $totalPages; i++) {
    #create an output name based on the current number
    $outName = "e" + $currentNumber.ToString('00000') + ".pdf"

    #output the one page
    pdftk input.pdf cat $currentNumber output $outName

    #increment currentNumber with one
    $currentNumber++
}
```

Comment: Again. This is a bit rough, but im sure this will put you on the right track like last question.

Answer (score 0):

Not working

This is what i did, changed your code a little:

```
$WorkDir = "D:\Bank\QR_ES\1_ES_Test"

chdir $WorkDir

$totalPages = pdftk QR.pdf dump_data | Select-String "NumberOfPages"

#First we determine our starting number by dropping the first letter from the filename and turning it into an integer.
$startingNumber = [int]$firstFile.substr(1)
$currentNumber = $startingNumber

#Now we iterate through every page we want to extract
For ($i = 1; i -le $totalPages; i++) {
    #create an output name based on the current number
    $outName = "e" + $currentNumber.ToString('00000') + ".pdf"

    #output the one page
    pdftk input.pdf cat $currentNumber output $outName

    #increment currentNumber with one
    $currentNumber++
}
```

And this is the error code, it's german though:

```
PS D:\Bank\QR_ES\1_ES_Test> C:\Users\Sasha\Desktop\Test.ps1
Es ist nicht möglich, eine Methode für einen Ausdruck aufzurufen, der den NULL hat.
In C:\Users\Sasha\Desktop\Test.ps1:8 Zeichen:1
+ $startingNumber = [int]$firstFile.substr(1)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
 
i : Die Benennung "i" wurde nicht als Name eines Cmdlet, einer Funktion, einer Skriptdatei oder eines ausführbaren Programms 
erkannt. Überprüfen Sie die Schreibweise des Namens, oder ob der Pfad korrekt ist (sofern enthalten), und wiederholen Sie den 
Vorgang.
In C:\Users\Sasha\Desktop\Test.ps1:12 Zeichen:14
+ For ($i = 1; i -le $totalPages; i++) {
+              ~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (i:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: the for loop should be for ($i = 1; $1 -le $totalPages; $i++)

Comment: Better, but not yet. I chopped the "QR.pdf" to only 40 pages. So now it exctracts the 40 pages and goes into an infinite loop: "e00039.pdf", "e00040.pdf" and then "e00390.pdf" and -> loop!

pdftk : Error: Range start page number exceeds size of PDF
In C:\Users\Sasha\Desktop\Test.ps1:17 Zeichen:5
+     pdftk QR.pdf cat $currentNumber output $outName
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Error: Range st...eds size of PDF:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
here: 66
input PDF has: 40 pages.
Exiting.

Comment: Although you already have a working answer, the error you're getting was because i formulated the for loop wrong again "$1 -le $totalPages" should be "$i -le $totalPages" ... Since 1 is always less or equal to $totalPages, it got stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: I just tried this again, didn't work: `($i = 1; $i -le $totalPages; $i++)`

Comment: Es ist nicht möglich, eine Methode für einen Ausdruck aufzurufen, der den NULL hat.
In Zeile:8 Zeichen:1
+ $startingNumber = [int]$firstFile.substr(1)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: "1" konnte nicht mit "NumberOfPages: 500" verglichen werden. Fehler: "Der Wert "NumberOfPages: 500" vom Typ 
"Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo" kann nicht in den Typ "System.Int32" konvertiert werden."
In Zeile:12 Zeichen:14
+ For ($i = 1; $i -le $totalPages; $i++) {
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComparisonFailure